# Generate views based on Entity?

Tags: java, jhipster

I'm migrating from Grails to JHipster, and one of the nice things about Grails is that based on a domain model, you can generate the views. I already have an existing domain model, and now I'd like to generate the views using JHipster, but, what I've seen so far, is that it's only possible to generate an entity, which I already have.

I have read the documentation, but am I missing something here?

Comment: I don't think it is possible, at least for the moment. It could be a nice feature.

Answer (score 0):

No, you are not. In jhipster, the views are generated when you generate the entities. The solution would be recreating them using jhipster:entity or  [jhipster-uml](http://jhipster.github.io/jhipster_uml.html). Cheers!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I disagree. I think you should read the question again. He says: "... what I've seen so far, is that it's only possible to generate an entity, which I already have. I have read the documentation, but am I missing something here?" The answer is no. It's not possible to generate only the views, since you have entities not generated by jhipster. That means he can stop looking for a way to generate the views.